# How to point php apache website to 2 urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have my website example www.example.com... I want that this should open with 2 urls.. Like if i open [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) or [www.example.com/eu](http://www.example.com/eu) then it should open same page. If my url is [www.example.com/products](http://www.example.com/products) or [www.example.com/eu/products](http://www.example.com/eu/products) then it must open same page...
means i want my website to work same on both base urls [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and [www.example.com/eu..](http://www.example.com/eu..).
Please help me on this. Any hint or pointers will be appreciated..do i need to do changes in htaccess or some where else to make it work?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do share your tried htaccess Rule file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Take a look in root folder, what `.htaccess` file do you have right now? if it is. Can you post it?  What have you tried?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/eu(/.*)$ $1 [QSA,END]
My requirement is my site should work same for base url localhost and localhost/eu

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?eu(/.*)?$ /$1 [QSA,END]
```

You obviously need the rewriting module to be loaded and activated for this to work. And you need to enable the interpretation of distributed configuration files (".htaccess") if you really want to use those instead of placing such rules into the actual http server's host configuration where they belong.

Comment: Hi arkascha, I tried the rewrite rule suggest by you in my .htaccess file.. When i open localhost then localhost works well, but when i open localhost/eu then i get page not found. My requirement is my website should work same for localhost and localhost/eu..

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I fixed the rule. The issue was the different way paths are handled in a `RewriteRule` depending on whether you are using the real host configuration or a distributed configuration file. The rule as shown above now works the same regardless of where you implement it.

Comment: Hi Arkascha,
This didn't work.. When i open localhost my website gets opened but when i open localhost/eu then get error page not found... My requirement is localhost and localhost/eu must open the same page... local/products and localhost/eu/products must open same page..

Comment: Above rule implements what you ask. If it "didn't work" for you, then you will need to find out _why_ it did not work for you. So you will need to start debugging. First: what does your http server's error log file say? Any new information in there? Second: did you local and enable the rewriting module? How? Third: Did you enable the interpretation of distributed configuration files as I mentioned? How did you make sure this actually works? Forth: Did you implement that rule at the correct location / position? Where _did_ you place it?

Comment: Hi arkascha,
If you can help me with this rule.. This rule works for localhost and localhost/eu...
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
What i can do to map localhost/eu/products to internally localhost/products but on browser it will show localhost/eu/products...

Comment: As said above: the rule shown in the answer does what you ask for. That is not the problem. The question is why it does not work for _you_ in _your_ setup. So: have you started debugging by answering the questions I asked?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [P]
This rule solve my half problem.. means it redirects localhost/eu to localhost and bowser shows localhost/eu... what should i change in this rule so that it should redirect localhost/eu/products to localhost/products.... means htaccess file remove /eu from every url..

Comment: Sorry, but since you repeatedly refuse to answer to any questions there is no way I can offer further assistance.